# React JS. Передать класс случайному элементу массива

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Всем здоровья! Подскажите, плиз, как организовать условие, чтобы показать не все картинки, а одну - рандомно. Кстати, даже так все не показываются, выдает ошибку: "Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop"... как быть?

```
    let [blockClass, setBlockClass] = useState("");

    let imageElements = props.images.map((image, i) => {
        return <img key={image.id} src={image} className={classNames(style.img, style[blockClass])}
                    id={style[`img` + i]} alt=""/>
    });


    let showImage = () => {
        setBlockClass("block");
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Код стоит приводить полностью.

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [items] = React.useState([1,2,3,4,5])
  const [random] = React.useState(Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length) + 1 )


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello random</h1>
      <h2>{items[random]}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень помогли, я получил отдельную картинку. Только еще подскажите плиз как передать ей класс... изначально у нее дисплей нон, только это часть мозайки и я должен класс передать именно картинке а не дивку в которой она лежит

Comment: @ЕрвандС-ян <h2><img style={{display: 'block'}} src={items[random].src} /></h2>


Не забывайте принимать ответ ^_^

Comment: Супер! Спасибо!